# How can I plot a convolution in MatLab?

Tags: function, matlab, plot, convolution

Can anyone explain to me how I would go about plotting a convolution in MatLab?

The function I am trying to plot is e^(-at)u(t)*u*t)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function for convolution of 2 arrays in Matlab is `conv(array1, array2)`. But I do not fully understand, the mathematic expression that you are trying to convolve.

To get the plot you would do something like

```
plot(conv(array1, array2));
```

To convolve the unit step function u(t) with u(t)e^(-at) you have to create the array of the unit step function

```
u = ones(1,n);
```

and you also have to create the array of the other function. With a for-loop for example

```
e = zeros(1,n);
for i=1:n
  e(i) = u(i)*exp(-a*i)
end
```

then convolve both and plot.

Comment: Oh, e(-at)u(t) is just the input function and it is being convoluted with the unit step function u(t).

Comment: @JustGoscha What does the n mean here?